# With parsing json via php (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I can't figure out what the problem is. I've tried everything possible, but experience with json is not enough. Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I will be very grateful for the corrected function code.

**Error**

> Undefined array key "gm_bk_id" {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]
> (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined array key "gm_bk_id"

**Code:**

```
    public function parse()
    {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path() . "/telnet.json"), true);
        $slots = $data['locator']['groups'];

        foreach($slots as $slot) {
            Slot::create([
                'game_id'       => $slot['gm_bk_id'],
                'title'         => $slot['gm_title'],
                'alias'         => $slot['gm_url'],
                'provider'      => $slot['gr_title'],
                'provider_type' => 'TELNET',
                'image'         => $slot['icons']
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('The list updated');
    }
```

**The JSON file from which you need to take the information**

```
{
   "success":true,
   "api":"ls-thy-by-yhr-id-get",
   "locator":{
      "ico_baseurl":"\/sdfsgre\/icons\/",
      "groups":[
         {
            "games":[
               {
                  "gm_is_board":false,
                  "gm_m_w":1280,
                  "gm_ln":20,
                  "gm_is_copy":true,
                  "gm_url":"Oeprjkg",
                  "gm_is_retro":false,
                  "gm_bk_id":1017,
                  "gm_d_w":1280,
                  "icons":[
                     {
                        "ic_h":221,
                        "ic_w":300,
                        "ic_name":"oeprjkg_300_221.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":135,
                        "ic_w":170,
                        "ic_name":"oeprjkg_170_135.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":101,
                        "ic_w":150,
                        "ic_name":"oeprjkg_150_101.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":220,
                        "ic_w":220,
                        "ic_name":"oeprjkg_220_220.jpg"
                     }
                  ],
                  "gm_title":"Oeprjkg",
                  "gm_m_h":720,
                  "gm_is_fs":true,
                  "gm_is_mobile":true,
                  "gm_is_pc":true,
                  "gm_new":false,
                  "gm_d_h":720
               },
               {
                  "gm_is_board":false,
                  "gm_m_w":1280,
                  "gm_ln":10,
                  "gm_is_copy":true,
                  "gm_url":"Tdfhhdf",
                  "gm_is_retro":false,
                  "gm_bk_id":1008,
                  "gm_d_w":1280,
                  "icons":[
                     {
                        "ic_h":221,
                        "ic_w":300,
                        "ic_name":"Tdfhhdf_300_221.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":135,
                        "ic_w":170,
                        "ic_name":"Tdfhhdf_170_135.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":101,
                        "ic_w":150,
                        "ic_name":"Tdfhhdf_150_101.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":220,
                        "ic_w":220,
                        "ic_name":"Tdfhhdf_220_220.jpg"
                     }
                  ],
                  "gm_title":"Tdfhhdf",
                  "gm_m_h":720,
                  "gm_is_fs":true,
                  "gm_is_mobile":true,
                  "gm_is_pc":true,
                  "gm_new":false,
                  "gm_d_h":720
               }
            ],
            "gr_title":"Tjtyuk",
            "gr_id":12
         },
         {
            "games":[
               {
                  "gm_is_board":false,
                  "gm_m_w":1280,
                  "gm_ln":4096,
                  "gm_is_copy":true,
                  "gm_url":"Idofjio",
                  "gm_is_retro":false,
                  "gm_bk_id":2001,
                  "gm_d_w":1280,
                  "icons":[
                     {
                        "ic_h":221,
                        "ic_w":300,
                        "ic_name":"Idofjio_300_221.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":135,
                        "ic_w":170,
                        "ic_name":"Idofjio_170_135.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":101,
                        "ic_w":150,
                        "ic_name":"Idofjio_150_101.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":220,
                        "ic_w":220,
                        "ic_name":"Idofjio_220_220.jpg"
                     }
                  ],
                  "gm_title":"Idofjio",
                  "gm_m_h":720,
                  "gm_is_fs":true,
                  "gm_is_mobile":true,
                  "gm_is_pc":true,
                  "gm_new":false,
                  "gm_d_h":720
               },
               {
                  "gm_is_board":false,
                  "gm_m_w":1280,
                  "gm_ln":243,
                  "gm_is_copy":true,
                  "gm_url":"Egdfhfgh",
                  "gm_is_retro":false,
                  "gm_bk_id":2000,
                  "gm_d_w":1280,
                  "icons":[
                     {
                        "ic_h":221,
                        "ic_w":300,
                        "ic_name":"Egdfhfgh_300_221.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":135,
                        "ic_w":170,
                        "ic_name":"Egdfhfgh_170_135.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":101,
                        "ic_w":150,
                        "ic_name":"Egdfhfgh_150_101.jpg"
                     },
                     {
                        "ic_h":220,
                        "ic_w":220,
                        "ic_name":"Egdfhfgh_220_220.jpg"
                     }
                  ],
                  "gm_title":"Egdfhfgh",
                  "gm_m_h":720,
                  "gm_is_fs":true,
                  "gm_is_mobile":true,
                  "gm_is_pc":true,
                  "gm_new":false,
                  "gm_d_h":720
               }
            ],
            "gr_title":"Egdfhfgh",
            "gr_id":19
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

ㅤ

Comment: You don't look to be taking the JSON structure fully into account. Have you called `dd(...)` before the error to see what is coming through? See what the data looks like that is causing the issue and it may become clear to you.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: "dd" means dump & die, and is a way of getting a variable dump from any PHP program (which Laraval is). Please check out: [dd reference](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-dd)

Comment: But more important than this bug, I would suggest that you Google some basic PHP and Laravel debugging techniques. Learning them will help you find the cause of the bug yourself and then its solution, and is much more helpful than any direct solution that you'll get here, trust me.

Answer (score 2):

The "gm_bk_id" key is nested within the "games" array, which is nested within the "groups" array. You need to iterate through these nested arrays correctly to access the "gm_bk_id" key.

```
public function parse()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path() . "/telnet.json"), true);
    $groups = $data['locator']['groups'];

    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $games = $group['games'];
        foreach ($games as $game) {
            Slot::create([
                'game_id'       => $game['gm_bk_id'],
                'title'         => $game['gm_title'],
                'alias'         => $game['gm_url'],
                'provider'      => $group['gr_title'],
                'provider_type' => 'TELNET',
                'image'         => $game['icons'][0]['ic_name'] // You might need to adjust this depending on how you want to store the image
            ]);
        }
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('The list updated');
}
```